# Ubuntu 20.04 : Wifi speed drops automatically

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, iwlwifi, download-speed

i have been suffering from this ever since I upgraded to my new ISP. Whenever I start my Linux, wifi speeds stay strong(60Mbps-70Mbps range). But after roughly an hour of usage, the speeds drp to 1-2Mbps range. it happens everytime. I even installed a fresh ubuntu 20.04.1 but this always happens.
The only solution that I know is that whenever I reboot my router, speeds go back up.
This only happens in Ubuntu. My windows and android phone work fine.
I have a dual boot configuration(win10/ubuntu)
Driver:- ath10k_pci
Version : driverversion=5.8.0-40-generic

Output for lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:08a6]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Are you doing the same thing in Ubuntu as you do in Windows? Downloading the same files visiting the same web sites? How are you measuring that there is a speed drop?

Comment: i am using speedtest.org to measure my connection speeds.

Comment: You might want to ask your ISP if they are doing any kind of throttling.

Comment: It's  a government company BSNL here in India, so it's kind of used by many. So I don't think that would be a problem cause many people are using it here and a lot of them use Linux. Also , if I would ask they wouldn't answer. If that is the problem, is there any solution to that?